# Blit surface on pygame display depending on mouse position

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

in this program I have a surface that has a grid on it. I'm trying to make a program that detects mouse position on surface and if my mouse is in one of the squares, the square turns green. The problem is that I've managed to get only 1 square working. I want all of the squares work like the one in upper left corner. Can anyone help?

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

WIDTH = 540
TILESIZE = 60
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREY = (211, 211, 211)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)


win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH+1, WIDTH+1))
win.fill(GREY)
surface = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE-1, TILESIZE-1))
surface.fill(RED)

def mouse_pos():
    surface_place = (1, 1)
    for x in range(0, 9, TILESIZE):
        for y in range(x):
            surface_place = list(surface_place)
            surface_place[0] += TILESIZE
            surface_place[1] += TILESIZE
            surface_place = tuple(surface_place)
            win.blit(surface, surface_place)

    if surface.get_rect().collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        win.blit(surface, surface_place)
        surface.fill(GREEN)
    else:
        win.blit(surface, surface_place)
        surface.fill(RED)

def draw_grid():
    for x in range(0, WIDTH+1, TILESIZE):
        pygame.draw.line(win, BLACK, (x, 0), (x, WIDTH))
    for y in range(0, WIDTH+1, TILESIZE):
        pygame.draw.line(win, BLACK, (0, y), (WIDTH, y))

clicked = False
while not clicked:
    draw_grid()
    mouse_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            clicked = True

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are of course multiple solutions to this.

One is to range/loop over `WIDTH`, like you do to draw the grid, and use some `Rect`-magic to draw the tile green or red, like this:

```
def mouse_pos():
    for x in range(1, WIDTH+1, TILESIZE):
        for y in range(1, WIDTH+1, TILESIZE):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, TILESIZE, TILESIZE).inflate(-1, -1)
            win.fill(GREEN if rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) else RED, rect)
```

Here we start the loop at `1` instead of `0` and shrink the rect by `1` pixel, using `inflate`, so we don't paint over the grid lines.

But what solution is right for you depends on what your trying to achieve in the end. Like, do you need a logical representation of your grid in your code? To you need to work with Surfaces instead of just filling a solid color?